# How do i import a list of files, choosing the name

Tags: import, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, files-and-directories

I have this list of files, i'm using FileNames[{"*.txt"}, NotebookDirectory[]] to import it, but i just want the ones without inelastic on the name.
How can i select just by the name? Thanks

> {"10.txt","11.txt","12.txt","13.txt","14.txt","15.txt","16.txt","17.txt","18.txt","19.txt","1.txt","20.txt","2.txt","3.txt","4.txt","5.txt","6.txt","7.txt","8.txt","9.txt","inelastico1.txt","inelastico2.txt","inelastico3.txt","inelastico4.txt","inelastico5.txt","inelastico6.txt","inelastico7.txt","inelasticov2-10.txt","inelasticov2-1.txt","inelasticov2-3.txt","inelasticov2-4.txt","inelasticov2-5.txt","inelasticov2-6.txt","inelasticov2-7.txt","inelasticov2-8.txt","inelasticov2-9.txt","inelasticov3-10.txt","inelasticov3-11.txt","inelasticov3-12.txt","inelasticov3-13.txt","*inelasticov3-14.txt","inelasticov3-14.txt","inelasticov3-15.txt","inelasticov3-16.txt","inelasticov3-1.txt","inelasticov3-2.txt","inelasticov3-3.txt","inelasticov3-4.txt","inelasticov3-5.txt","inelasticov3-6.txt","inelasticov3-7.txt","inelasticov3-8.txt","inelasticov3-9.txt"}

Comment: Say `lst` is your list. `DeleteCases[lst, x_ /; StringMatchQ[x, ___ ~~ "inelastic" ~~ ___]]` will give you the list sans any with "inelastic" as part of name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the file list without the files containing "inelastic", you can use:

```
Cases[{your file list here}, x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, "*inelastic*"] == False]
```

Then, to import them:

```
Import[#] & /@ %
```

One-step solution:

```
Import[#] & /@ 
 Cases[{your file list here}, 
  x_String /; StringMatchQ[x, "*inelastic*"] == False]
```

---

**Edit**: Out of curiosity, I tried to trim the file list without using StringMatchQ, and using Pick with StringCases seems to work as, per its documentation, StringCases can thread over a list.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
StringCases[fileList, ___ ~~ "inelastic" ~~ ___]
(* {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \
{}, {}, {}, {"inelastico1.txt"}, {"inelastico2.txt"}, \
{"inelastico3.txt"}, {"inelastico4.txt"}, {"inelastico5.txt"}, \
{"inelastico6.txt"}, {"inelastico7.txt"}, {"inelasticov2-10.txt"}, \
{"inelasticov2-1.txt"}, {"inelasticov2-3.txt"}, \
{"inelasticov2-4.txt"}, {"inelasticov2-5.txt"}, \
{"inelasticov2-6.txt"}, {"inelasticov2-7.txt"}, \
{"inelasticov2-8.txt"}, {"inelasticov2-9.txt"}, \
{"inelasticov3-10.txt"}, {"inelasticov3-11.txt"}, \
{"inelasticov3-12.txt"}, {"inelasticov3-13.txt"}, \
{"*inelasticov3-14.txt"}, {"inelasticov3-14.txt"}, \
{"inelasticov3-15.txt"}, {"inelasticov3-16.txt"}, \
{"inelasticov3-1.txt"}, {"inelasticov3-2.txt"}, \
{"inelasticov3-3.txt"}, {"inelasticov3-4.txt"}, \
{"inelasticov3-5.txt"}, {"inelasticov3-6.txt"}, \
{"inelasticov3-7.txt"}, {"inelasticov3-8.txt"}, \
{"inelasticov3-9.txt"}} *)

Pick[fileList, StringCases[fileList, ___ ~~ "inelastic" ~~ ___], {}]
(* {"10.txt","11.txt","12.txt","13.txt","14.txt","15.txt","16.txt",\
"17.txt","18.txt","19.txt","1.txt","20.txt","2.txt","3.txt","4.txt",\
"5.txt","6.txt","7.txt","8.txt","9.txt"} *)
```

Interestingly, StringCases don't seem to work with the * pattern since only StringMatchQ seems to work with what's called "abbreviated string patterns".

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
StringCases[fileList, "*inelastic*"]
(* {{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \
{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \
{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \
{}, {}} *)
```

---

**Edit 2**: I just realized that StringMatchQ (and StringFreeQ) also threads across a list, so you can also do it like this (tweaks to StringFreeQ from @Mr.Wizard):

```
Pick[fileList, StringFreeQ[fileList, "inelastic"], True]
```

or

```
Pick[fileList, StringMatchQ[fileList, "*inelastic*"], False]
```

Note that only StringMatchQ (and not even StringFreeQ) can use the * notation.

```
Pick[fileList, StringFreeQ[fileList, "*inelastic*"], True]
(* this will give incorrect answer *)
```

All of the methods have identical speed (0.) for your example but I have no clue about their relative speeds for a large input.

Comment: I missed your use of `StringFreeQ` before posting my answer, but you are making its use more complicated that necessary.  Take a look. (And +1.)

Answer (score 5):

I would use [`StringFreeQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringFreeQ.html):

```
(* files = {"10.txt", "11.txt", . . ., "inelasticov3-8.txt", "inelasticov3-9.txt"}; *)

Select[files, StringFreeQ[#, "inelastic"] &]
```

> ```
>  {"10.txt", "11.txt", "12.txt", "13.txt", "14.txt", "15.txt", "16.txt", "17.txt", 
>   "18.txt", "19.txt", "1.txt", "20.txt", "2.txt", "3.txt", "4.txt", "5.txt", "6.txt", 
>   "7.txt", "8.txt", "9.txt"}
> ```

Or:

```
# ~Pick~ StringFreeQ[#, "inelastic"] & @ files
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the better use of StringFreeQ! You have the most elegant answer to this question by far.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the pattern `"*inelastic*.txt"` in `FileNames`.  This will only return the list of files you need.

Then use `Map` with pure functions (`Function`) to import all of them in one go: `Import[#, "Table"]& /@ fileNames` or similar.

---

To use everything *except* file names with "inelastic", you can use `Select,`Cases`,`DeleteCases`, etc. with`StringMatchQ`.

Example:

```
Select[fileNames, Not@StringMatchQ[#, "*inelastic*"] &]
```

Comment: Thanks but that way i only choose the one I don't want

Comment: I tried 1*.txt and it works but left me out the ones with one number

Comment: @user18508 answer updated